# How to create dashboard with multiple pages in Python

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have a dashboard with 4 pages and have managed to create different content for each page in a very basic way using a dbc.navbar for an example.

But what I am attempting now is to have a different chart layout for each page.
I am aware that it is built on columns and rows but cannot get my head around it.

Here is my code for the dashboard

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output #for the callbacks


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.DARKLY])

# the style arguments for the sidebar. We use position:fixed and a fixed width
SIDEBAR_STYLE = {
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": 0,
    "left": 0,
    "bottom": 0,
    "width": "16rem",
    "padding": "2rem 1rem",
    "background-color": "black",
}

# the styles for the main content position it to the right of the sidebar and
# add some padding.
CONTENT_STYLE = {
    "margin-left": "18rem",
    "margin-right": "2rem",
    "padding": "2rem 1rem",
}

sidebar = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2("Sidebar", className="display-4"),
        html.Hr(),
        html.P(
            "A simple sidebar layout with navigation links", className="lead"
        ),
        dbc.Nav(
            [
                dbc.NavLink("Home", href="/", active="exact"),
                dbc.NavLink("Page 1", href="/page-1", active="exact"),
                dbc.NavLink("Page 2", href="/page-2", active="exact"),
                dbc.NavLink("Page 3", href="/page-3", active="exact"),
            ],
            vertical=True,
            pills=True,
        ),
    ],
    style=SIDEBAR_STYLE,
)

content = html.Div(id="page-content", style=CONTENT_STYLE)
header = html.H4(
    "Side Example.py", className="bg-primary text-white p-2 mb-2 text-center"
)

app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Location(id="url"),sidebar,header,content])


@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"),[Input("url", "pathname")])
     #Output("line-chart", "figure"),
    

def render_page_content(pathname):
    if pathname == "/":
        return dbc.NavbarSimple(children=[html.H2('Particular info for HOMEPAGE')],color="grey",dark=True,)
    elif pathname == "/page-1":
        return dbc.NavbarSimple(children=[html.H2('Particular info for PAGE1')],color="grey",dark=True,)
    elif pathname == "/page-2":
        return dbc.NavbarSimple(children=[html.H2('Particular info for PAGE2')],color="grey",dark=True,)
    # If the user tries to reach a different page, return a 404 message
    return dbc.Jumbotron(
        [
            html.H1("404: Not found", className="text-danger"),
            html.Hr(),
            html.P(f"The pathname {pathname} was not recognised..."),
        ]
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(port=8001)
```

A basic drawing example of what I am trying to accomplish is in the images below

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I undestand correctly, but you can just change the children list. For each page you can  create a new children list with the content and layout that you need. Something like this:

```
# Fill content
children_list_1 = list()
children_list_2 = list()

children_list_1.append(html.H1(id="title1",children="Page_1",style=dict(display="flex", justifyContent="center"),))
children_list_1.append(dash_table.DataTable(....))
...
children_list_2.append(html.H1(id="title2",children="Page_2",style=dict(display="flex", justifyContent="center"),))
children_list_2.append(html.Div([html.H3("some graph:"), dcc.Graph(id="asd", figure={})], className="six columns"))
...

def render_page_content(pathname):
    if pathname == "/":
        return dbc.NavbarSimple(children=[html.H2('Particular info for HOMEPAGE')],color="grey",dark=True,)
    elif pathname == "/page-1":
        return children_list_1
    elif pathname == "/page-2":
        return children_list_2
    # If the user tries to reach a different page, return a 404 message
    return dbc.Jumbotron(
        [
            html.H1("404: Not found", className="text-danger"),
            html.Hr(),
            html.P(f"The pathname {pathname} was not recognised..."),
        ]
    )
```